# Executing Multiple scala Object using single Spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi Have Created One Maven Project(spark/scala) using Eclipse and have 4 scala Object in that Project(1st_layer.scala,2nd_layer.scala,3rd_layer.scala,4th_layer.scala).I have generated my project jar(/home/test/Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar).NowI want to run these all layer using spark submit command.

```
    spark-submit --master local[*]  --class com.pkg.data.1st_layer  /home/test /Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Could you please give  me a hint how can I pass all the the classes(1st_layer,2nd_layer,3rd_layer,4th_layer) using single spark submit.
Note(all the layers are dependent(dataload,transform..etc).

Sample Layer code :

```
object Layer1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //created spark session
    var a1 = sparksession.sql(" loadstmt")
    sparksession.stop()
  }
}

object Layer2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //created spark session
    var a1 = sparksession.sql(" insert and select(temp) st")
    sparksession.stop()
  }
}

object Layer3 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //created sparksession
    var a1 = sparksession.sql(" insert and select(orc)")
    sparksession.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your Class program where you have included these scala objects.

Comment: question is broad narrow it to specific requirements. ETL can be done with single spark driver which data load step and tranform step etc... in each step you can call different encapsulated objects Main Driver -> object DataLoadStep -> object TranformStep etc...  its very common pattern in spark world

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram I'm new to Programming and Spark.could you please help me how should I do that I have created 4 different scala/spark objects.In which in 1st layer i m loading data into temp table from csv file then i m again loading into one hive table into orc format and in third layer i'm applying all the transformations while loading into final table.

Comment: @Raghavendra Gupta...Please see the below sample code(flow)not sharing  the exact code.

Comment: object 1st_layer {        
def main(args: Array[String]) {        
//created sparksession        
 var a1=sparksession.sql(" loadstmt")        
sparksession.stop()        
}        
}        
object 2nd_layer {        
def main(args: Array[String]) {        
//created sparksession        
var a1=sparksession.sql(" insert and select(temp) st")        
sparksession.stop()}}        
object 3rd_layer {        
def main(args: Array[String]) {        
//sparksession        
var a1=sparksession.sql(" insert and select(orc)")        
sparksession.stop() }        
}

Comment: You can execute 4 spark-submit commands in 1 shell script by running them one after the other. Just have control using return code etc.

Comment: Create spark session in individual scala files.. I guess no need of class file too to control them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options

1) *Executing spark-submit with single driver.*

2) *Executing multiple spark-submits i.e. one for each....*

As you want to do with in one spark submit and driver you can do this.

You can use single driver by passing arguents to driver you can bypass the flow and you can execute the steps (like load transform) in isolation(separately) as well as at a shot you can execute the ETL steps in algorithm.

This is the sample code (instead of multiple class/object I used one function for each step, although you can use different object to encapsulate your logic and is optional) :

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object ETLDriver {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("ETLDriver").master("local").getOrCreate()
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)

  import spark.implicits._

  def layer1() = {
    //created spark session
    var a1 = spark.sql(" loadstmt")
  }

  def layer2() {
    //created spark session
    var a1 = spark.sql(" insert and select(temp) st")
  }

  def layer3() {
    //created sparksession
    var a1 = spark.sql(" insert and select(orc)")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
// you can pass arguments through your spark submit to by pass the flow  here I have
    // not included since its a sudo code.
    layer1()
    layer2()
    layer3()
  }
}
```

***example Spark submit would look like below***

```
    spark-submit --master local[*]  --class examples.ETLDriver  /home/test /Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

If your ETL steps are dependent then you can use a single spark driver to do this.

> #### Conclusion :
>
> *Executing separate `spark-submit` i.e. Option 2 you are getting sparksession again and again for all the 3 steps you mentioned. will
>   take some time to get hold of session and excute the job.Hence I would
>   clearly prefer option 1*

Comment: I gave psedo code example. you can just check that and ask questions if required.

Comment: @ Ram Ghadiyaram yes tried 2nd option and it worked.will try first option now.Thanks a lot!!                                                                                                 have One more Question Posted Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984121/spark-sql-optimization-techniques kindly help if you any any suggestion.Thanks In Advance @Ram Ghadiyaram

Comment: it should work i have practical experience (specially on 1st option) on this kind of requirements and worked like a charm