# Spark sql Optimization Techniques loading csv to orc format of hive

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have 90 GB data In CSV file I'm loading this data into one temp table and then from temp table to orc table using select insert command but for converting and loading data into orc format its taking 4 hrs in spark sql.Is there any kind of optimization technique which i can use to reduce this time.As of now I'm not using any kind of optimization technique I'm just using spark sql and loading data from csv file to table(textformat) and then from this temp table to orc table(using select insert)
  using spark submit as:

```
    spark-submit \
    --class class-name\
    --jar file
```

or can I add any extra Parameter in spark submit for improving the optimization.

scala code(sample):

```
    All Imports
    object demo {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //sparksession with enabled hivesuppport

    var a1=sparksession.sql("load data inpath 'filepath'  overwrite into table table_name")

    var b1=sparksession.sql("insert into tablename (all_column) select 'ALL_COLUMNS' from    source_table")

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just using spark sql and loading data from csv file to
>   table(textformat) and then from this temp table to orc table(using
>   select insert)

---

2 step process is not needed here..

- Read the dataframe like below sample...

```
val DFCsv = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load("yourcsv")
```

- if needed you have to do `repartition`(may be this is cause of the actual 4hr delay since you have not done) since its large file and then...

`dfcsv.repartition(90)` means it will/may repartition the csv data in to 90 almost equal parts. where 90 is sample number. you can mention what ever you want.

```
      DFCsv.write.format("orc")
    .partitionBy('yourpartitioncolumns')
    .saveAsTable('yourtable')
```

OR

```
     DFCsv.write.format("orc")
     .partitionBy('yourpartitioncolumns')
     .insertInto('yourtable')
```

> Note:  1) For large data you need to do repartition to uniformly distribute the data will increase the parllelism and hence
>   performance.
>
> 2) If you dont have patition columns and is
>   non-partition table then no need of `partitionBy` in the above
>   samples

Comment: How should i do repartition .In my Orc table I have Partition Column,but when i am trying to save my df using:

Comment: DFCsv.write.format("orc").partitionBy('yourpartitioncolumns').saveAsTable('dbname.yourtable')

Comment: its showing database not found issue.and if i m not specifying any database name then its saving table in some default database I checked in my all the databases its not showing this table anywhere,but when i m againg running that same command without database name its showing default.tablename already exists.

Comment: DFCsv.write.format("orc").partitionBy('yourpartitioncolumns').saveAsTable('yourtable')         Or is there any kind of spark submit configuration which i can pass to improve this performance?

Comment: you have to pass number of executor , core , executor memory , driver memory as per the requirements in spark-submit command.  Reg. Another question, "database not found " means you have to mention existing database/create and mention the database. .... my solution should work in any case.

Comment: dfcsv.repartition(90) means it will/may repartition the csv data in to 90 almost equal parts. this has nothing to do with your hive table level partition column.

Comment: Reg. Another question, "database not found "-->Yes I'm Using Existing Database only I'm able to select data from same Database.tablename for creating DF but not able to save dataframe in same database while saving dataframe into table its showing database not found.

Comment: `spark.sql("show databases").show()` will display all databases. but this is separate question not related to peformance tuning. Users will get confused if you mix up.