# Executing All Objects in A Package Sequentially With Spark Submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I'm looking for a way to execute all scala objects in a package sequentially using spark submit. Working on an ETL job. I have 4 scala objects (let say **Object_1**, **Object_2**, **Object_3** and **Object_4**) all in one package,let's say *etl*. This package is then exported to a .jar file (say *all_four.jar*)

- **EXTRACTION** - Object_1 and Object_2
- **TRANSFORMATION** - Object_3
- **LOAD** - Object_4

I know I can execute each object with the following spark submit command

```
./spark-submit --class etl.x --jars path/to/jar/if/any.jar path/to/exported/jar/all_four.jar arg(0)......arg(n)
```

where x represents each scala objects in the package.

However, I'm looking for a way to call the package only once and all objects will be executed in the following sequence:

- Step 1 - Object_1 and Object_2 (Extraction) can be executed concurrently or maybe simultaneously. They just have to be both completed
- Step 2 - Object_3 (Transformation ) is executed
- Step 3 - Object_4 (Load) is executed

Is there a way to do this with Spark Submit? Or are there better and more efficient ways to pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to write wrapper object (`Execute`) which contains step 1, step 2 & step 3 logics to invoke all in sequence. This wrapper object you can include along with those four objects if you have source code access.

Please find sample wrapper looks like below & You may need to modify according your need.

```
import etl.{Object_1,Object_2,Object_3,Object_4}

object Execute {

    def extract() = {
      // Make use of Object_1 & Object_2 logic here.
    }
    
    def transform() {
      // Make use of Object_3 logic here.
    }
    
    def load() {
      // Make use of Object_4 logic here.   
    }
    
    def main(args: Array[String])  
    {        
       extract()
       transform()
       load()      
    } 
    
}
```

```
./spark-submit \
--class Execute \
--jars path/to/jar/if/any.jar path/to/exported/jar/all_four.jar arg(0)......arg(n)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Please can you help with creating the wrapper object or point me to a link where I can see how it's done as I'm not really versed like that. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I tried something like this but I had some challenges. I posted the code in the link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898395/executing-multiple-scala-object-using-single-spark-submit/62686784#62686784

Comment: can you explain what challenges are you facing ??

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I tried something like this but I had some challenges. I posted the code in the link here as an answer in the link because I do not have enough reputations yet to make a comment on questions that's not mine: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898395/executing-multiple-scala-object-using-single-spark-submit/62686784#62686784. Can you help provide input on why filepath is not being parsed into the four objects despite it being in the Main Object (testing_1). How can I call the filepath from the Object(testing_1) and use it in (layers 1 to 4).

Comment: can you post what content that file has ??

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Though not precisely was I was gunning for but at least I was able to get it to work and get the job done, all thanks to your efforts. I truly appreciate.